# make google voice forwarding number the same

Tags: sms, tasker, google-voice

I have a tasker script that triggers based on number. Is there a way to keep my Google Voice number the same? I am giving my Google Voice number out to the public and I don't want anyone to know my real number. If Voice can't do this, is there another way?

Edit: 
I am sorry, what I am trying to do is forward sms based on Google Voice. I already have it set up in Google Voice to forward any SMS it receives over to my personal cell, however, the number it uses keeps changing and I have a tasker script that then forwards that SMS to another number. I am use Google Voice because I don't want to give out my personal cell, and the number that I need to forward to is a short code which Google can't do. –

Comment: I find this confusing and unclear what you are asking... Your Google Voice number doesn't change, it will always be the same. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Where does Tasker come in? Can you explain that. And please explain the rest of the question.

Comment: Trying to read between the lines, and I'm thinking that maybe what you're trying to do is, when someone calls your GV number, and it forward to your real number, you want your phone to display the callers number instead of your gv? Is this a good guess?